# Where can I store custom documents of custom beamer themes?

Tags: beamer

I am using TeX Live 2012 in Ubuntu 12.04. I have downloaded some custom `beamer` themes and put them in `~/texmf`. But I have no idea where to put the manual of the `beamer`s.

BTW, besides `texdoc`, is there other ways to check the document of a package? I tried `texdoc tikz` and `texdoc pgf` but the result is not the 700+ pages pgf manual.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) 1) I'm not sure I understand the question. Package manuals *do not have to be* anywhere for the package to work (when loaded). 2) I don't know about MikTeX but TeX Live keeps a local copy of the packages' manuals; they're accessible through TeX Live Utility >> packages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The main question is the first one. Yes the beamer themes work. But I hope I can check the manual easily when I use the themes. I don't want to maintain a lot of manual myself.

Comment: You should put the themes inside, say, `~/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/themes`; docs can go into `~/texmf/doc/latex/beamer/themes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents would belong in `~/texmf/doc/latex/beamer/` or some subdirectory of this.  You can get `texdoc` to list files matching e.g. `pgf` via the `-l` option:

```
texdoc -l pgf
```

yields 24 results on my system.  The `-s` option will list even more.